# How to keep (or import) the Tor Browser's history, when updating from an older version to TBB 5.0?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, update

Is it possible to keep (or import) the Tor Browser's history data (not the bookmarks) when updating from an older version to TBB 5.0? And if so, then how?

Background: Using TBB as my "default browser" for almost one year now with LinuxMint, I somewhen decided to switch on the browsing history, as well as address completion and decent caching (due to data limits on my mobile internet connection).

I haven't agreed to update ever since though, because the former manual TBB update process would dispose of all the convenient history and completion data :-(

While trying out the new TBB 5.0 I discovered that it has a nice+smooth Auto-Updater (similar to the normal Firefox-Updater) which will probably keep 
these data from now on. Now that is great work, Thanks a lot! - But still, how can I transfer my old browsing history into the new version 5.0?

P.S. In case there is NO way - then how can I start-up the old TBB in an "offline mode" (i.e. without connecting to the Tor network), to use it just as a reference when searching for an old page address I can't remember any more?

Thank you very much in advance for any reply!
Warm regards from Dresden, Germany -
Ulf

Answer (score 1):

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile#w_bookmarks-and-browsing-history
Replace Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/places.sqlite file with old one.

Comment: Wow, precise brillant answer - worked for me right away (of course I had to switch-on caching and browsing history etc. in TBB 5 first ;) The web link also gives details on auto-complete history, passwords, certs etc.! Actually I did not expect an answer at all - the less in an few hours :-) So it was rather worthwhile to dig up some broken English for posting this question! Thank you very much indeed, dear user8143!!!
Roger & Out, Ulf